# 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, pdo

I am facing with this problem today, while trying to connect to a remote mysql on a network. Framework used Laravel 5.3. I have configured properly the .env file with exact credentials. Yesterday was working fine.

Comment: `No route to host` sounds like a network problem

Comment: This means the destination your trying to reach is not available. Check your routing credentials. And please post your code so we can also see if there is a spelling error. Provide some code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems, that you have a network problem. Usually on a network ip changes from time to time. Please check the `IP` of the remote pc or computer on the network. If `IP` has changed, update again the .env file. Good luck.

Comment: Hell Dean! Thank you for your answer. Yes it was the `IP` problem. Host had changed. My bad.

Comment: the moment I read "if IP has changed" I knew what the issue was. Thanks.