# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am creating a pdo data connection. The connections works fine on localhost. 
But when I connect to my remote db, and use exactly the same credentials which I have used before, I get a empty page, no error messages, just a empty page.

The same credentials that are working on a previous project were done with mysqli, this one is done with pdo.

I have tried two types of pdo connection code, none of them are working.

First one:

```
$databaseHost = 'x.xxx.xxx.xx';
$databaseName = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$databaseUsername = 'xxxxxxx';
$databasePassword = 'xxxxxx';
$charset = 'utf8';

try {

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$databaseHost;dbname=$databaseName;charset=$charset";


} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        ];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $opt);
```

Second one:

```
$databaseHost = 'x.xxx.xxx.xx';
$databaseName = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$databaseUsername = 'xxxxxxx';
$databasePassword = 'xxxxxx';

$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        ];

try {

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$databaseHost};dbname={$databaseName}", $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $opt);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Even though both connections work in localhost, I tried to just load this connection page locally in the browser, the fist option gave me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation
>   timed out in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ijdb_pdo/config.php:24 Stack
>   trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ijdb_pdo/config.php(24):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=83.1...', 'u1164707_sohail', 'sohail123',
>   Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ijdb_pdo/config.php on line 24

and the second option gave me the following error:

> againtestConnection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out

What am i messing up in my code?

I tried then to connect through the terminal with:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:/ sohail$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -h "xx.xxx.xxx.xx" -u "xxxxxx" "-pxxxxxxx" "xxxxxxx";
```

and got the following error:

> Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be
>   insecure. ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' (60) MacBook-Pro-3:/ sohail$

I don't think I have terminal access on my remote machine, so I can't do SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT'; cmd
-thanks

Comment: Is it possible that MySQL is using a different port number on your server?

Comment: how would I be able to find out if there exits a port number. I have phpMyAdmin running on the server. 
I am working locally on mysqlWorkbench, and was not able to create a remote connection, so that could have been a reason for that?

Comment: If you have command line access on the server, log in to the mysql command line and then type: show variables;
The port number will be in there.

Comment: I don't know yet if I have command line access on the server, but tried to connect from my terminal with the proper credentials, but got the reply: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' (60)
But if this is a port access issue, then I shouldn't have been able to create a previous project with the same credentials, even though the former project was created with mysqli and not pdo as the current one.

Comment: just found out that the port nr is 3306, buts its written as 3 306, would that matter?

Comment: Sure, the space could affect it.

Answer (score 2):

For your second error, with reference to these two answers.

[PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out on my local computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897406/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-timed-out-on-my-local-computer)

['PDOExcpetion' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544391/pdoexcpetion-with-message-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-route-to-host)

Either you need to enable the access to remote database or you have network IP issue which changes time to time. Please verify both things. I hope this will help you.

Comment: next time, do not post an answer but vote to close with one of these links

Comment: you are absolutely right but i didn't have privileges to comment while i want to help him.. Thanks

Comment: I forgot to start my VPN :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
somehow the database connection credential was changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a Laravel App in Vagrant. I cleared the config cache and then it worked fine.

```
php artisan config:cache
```